# Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have the following domains

```
class User {

    Boolean accountLocked
    String password
    Boolean passwordExpired
    Boolean enabled
    String username
    String name
    String surname
    String gender
    String urlPicture
    String cellphone
    String address
    Integer pc
    String permission
    String email
    Date created
    Boolean accountExpired

    static hasMany = [
        customerOnlines: CustomerOnline,
        partners: Partner,
        roles: Role,
        salesmans: Salesman,
        subsidiaries: Subsidiary
    ]

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
        id generator: 'identity'
        table '`user`'
        password column: '`password`'
        email unique: true
    }

    static constraints = {
        accountLocked nullable: true, default: false
        password nullable: true
        passwordExpired nullable: true, default: false
        enabled nullable: true, default: true
        username nullable: true, maxSize: 45
        name nullable: true, maxSize: 45
        surname nullable: true, maxSize: 100
        gender nullable: true, maxSize: 15
        urlPicture nullable: true
        cellphone nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        address nullable: true
        pc nullable: true
        permission nullable: true
        created nullable: true
        accountExpired nullable: true, default: false
    }

    class Subsidiary {

        String subsidiaryName
        Date dob
        User user

        static hasMany = [
            partners: Partner,
            phones: Phone,
            salesmans: Salesman
        ]
        static belongsTo = [Partner, User]

        static mapping = {
            id generator: "identity"
            version false
        }

        static constraints = {
            subsidiaryName nullable: true, maxSize: 100
            dob nullable: true
        }
```

The problem is while trying to create a new subsidiary

```
    def save(Subsidiary subsidiary) {

    System.out.println(params)
    def usuario = new User(name:params.name,surname:params.surname,address:params.address,cellphone:params.cellphone,gender:params.gender,username:params.username,password:params.password,pc:params.pc)
    usuario.save flush:true
    def subsidiaria= new Subsidiary(name:params.namesub,user:usuario)


    subsidiaria.save flush:true



    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'subsidiary.label', default: 'Subsidiary'), subsidiary.id])
            redirect view: 'create'
        }
        '*' { respond subsidiary, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

I get the error not-null property references a null or transient value on `subsidiaria.save flush:true` however I'm not able to find the problem, and even if I use `usuario.addToSubsidiaries(subsidiaria).save()` it still does not work at all and
keeps giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the problem was with the controller itself, unfortunately I had to put all the params of both tables like this

```
     user.accountLocked=params.accountLocked
     user.password=params.password
     user.passwordExpired=params.passwordExpired
     user.enabled=params.enabled
     user.username=params.username
     user.name=params.name
     user.surname=params.surname
     user.gender=params.gender
     user.urlPicture=params.urlPicture
     user.cellphone=params.cellphone
     user.address=params.address
     user.pc=params.pc
     user.permission=params.permission
     user.email=params.email
     user.created=params.created
     user.accountExpired=params.accountExpired
```

immediately I saved like

```
     user.save flush:true
     user.addToSubsidiaries(subsidiary)
     user.save flush:true
```

after that both tables were updated with new information provided, looks like grails could not handle 2 different beans at the same time.